Blender scale animation on armature goes haywire when exported
I have a complex character rig done by me in Blender and the models based on it imported seemingly nicely into Unity until now. I unfortunately can't share the model or it's image by now.
Things start to go awry when I animate paws scale and put arms stretch-and-squash into the mix: they animate as expected within Blender, with scales transfering when set to, but the exported model stretch horrifically in Unity, like all scales and stretches started to build-up one on top of the other with no compensation for parents transforms or else.

I have tried to export the model in different ways, including Apply Transforms on and off and changing the way scale is transfered to involved bones (Properties > Bone > Relations > Inherit Scale set to None and others), but nothing seems to work.

I haven't tried yet anything with Relative Parenting (Properties > Bone > Relations > Relative Parenting) off (it's on along most of the deforming bones, if not all) due to time pressure and I've just removed squash-and-stretch and scale from the animation for now.

The problem is not in Unity, as reimporting the FBX model into Blender shows the exact same problem. So: exported FBX != Blender animated model.

All search I do lead me to other kind of common Blender-to-Unity scale problem (namely the 0.01 scale factor in the entire thing), but that's something I've already got right.


Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Exporter settings (which give correct orientation and correct skeleton scale withing Unity):
✔ Selected Objects
> Transform
    Scale: 1.0
    Apply Scalings: FBX Units Scale
    Forward: -Z Forward
    Up: Y Up
    ✔ Apply Unit
    ✔ Use Space Transform
    ✔ Apply Transform ⚠
> Armature
    Primary Bone Axis: +Y Axis
    Secondary Bone Axis: X Axis
    Armaure FBXNode Type: Null
    ✔ Only Deform Bones
    ✔ Add Leaf Bones
> ✔ Animation
    ✔ Key All Bones
    ✔ NLA Strips
    ✔ All Actions
    ✔ Force Start/End Keying
    Sampling Rate: 1.0
    Simplify: 1.0

